# Dispose the thread and delete the file associated to that thread

Tags: multithreading, dispose

I want to dispose the process thread and delete a file associated to that thread. So I am being able to dispose the thread but while deleting the file, it still says that the file is being is being used by the process.

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(outputTool, matchPattern)
{
  var prcInfo = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(match.Value));
  var threadCollection = prcInfo.Threads;
  foreach (ProcessThread thread in threadCollection)
  {
    thread.Dispose();
  }                         
  File.Delete(filePaths[0]);
}
```

Comment: What platform is this? File locking and thread semantics are platform specific.

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: This question appears to be based on the assumption that ProcessThread.Dispose() will also force the thread to stop.  Wrong assumption, Process.Kill() will be necessary to do that.

Comment: Hans, the thing is process.kill() will stop it but right now that process is the main process in the system i am working with , which i don't want to kill. i just want to kill the thread. i have tried doing process.kill(), it does work for me, I am just trying to figure out if we can del a file by killing the threads used by the process.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have left a file handle open.  Make sure you close the file and handle before trying to delete the file.

Comment: How do we close handle in c#, well i did tried to dump all the handle info, from command prompt using handle -a filename, in that case it says no matching handles found. but still after trying to dispose the thread and delete the file, it still says file has been  used by another process.